# Is Juju for automating installation of web application for customers?

Tags: juju, hosting

I have written a software in ROR that I want to host it for customers by own. These are some examples:

```
vanillaforums.com/plans
manage.nodebb.org
wordpress.com
ghost.org/pricing
```

What I need is a software to automate installation per user and allow them to manage their space (installing plugins, editing source, etc). can [Juju](http://juju.ubuntu.com) handle this service?